# При запуске игнорируется код или отсутствует кнопка пуска

Tags: java

Задача: Создать класс с тремя полями, одно из которых должно быть защищено private, а также для него должны быть созданы сеттер и геттер. Также в классе должно быть 3 метода.

Отсутствует кнопка запуска программы.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5PqO.png)

Если добавить строку public static void main (String[] args), то кнопка запуска появляется, но в консоли ничего не выводится.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmzLV.png)

Как видно на скринах, ошибок никаких не подчёркивает. Работаю в Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос текстом.

Comment: и название класса все-таки измени на student)) Вроде ничего такого, но по ощущениям увидел какое-то извращение

Comment: @RottenRat, имя класса кириллицей -- не самое страшное на этих скриншотах.

Comment: @K3relin, какой результат вы ожидаете, создав _пустой_ метод `main`?  Зачем вы инициализируете _поля_ класса путём вызова методов чтения консоли??  Вы понимаете, что при попытке создания экземпляра такого класса, приложение тихо зависнет, ожидая ввода _всех трёх полей_, и только после этого начнут выполняться нестатические блоки?

Comment: `При запуске игнорируется код` -- что именно игнорируется в вашем коде?

Answer (score 1):

В Java выполнение программы начинается с psvm. Вы его добавляете, но в нем нет инструкций, соответственно, выполняться нечему.